# Laravel 4 bypass maintenance mode for a route

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

I have put my application down for maintenance using `php artisan down` command.

My custom maintenance page as a email input to accept the email from the user and store in my database to notify the user when the site is back up and running again.

But when I submit the form using POST, I get redirected to the maintenance mode page.

I want one particular route to bypass the maintenance mode. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so I found a way to go about this problem.

In my `app/routes` file, I have a route as follows:

```
// app/routes.php
Route::resource('subscriber', 'SubscriberController');
```

Now this will route will match any request URI for the form `subscriber*`

In my `app/start/global.php` file, I did the following inside `App::down()`

```
// app/start/global.php
App::down(function() {

    if(Request::is('subscriber*')) {
        return null;
    }

    return Response::view('maintenance', array(), 503);
})
```

Now only for URIs of starting with `subscriber`, the maintenance mode page will not be displayed.

:D